# Почему не cрабатывают ссылки на IOS устройствах при прикосновениях?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Все навигационные ссылки на сайте включая выпадающее меню и кнопки на IOS устройствах не реагируют на прикосновения. На других же устройствах все работает нормально. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Вот сайт karvon.kz

Comment: попробуйте библиотечку [fastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нас Mac OS Safari  8.0.7  не работает тоже, видимо проблема в том, что прелоадер с id="hellopreloader" у вас не убирается до конца, как показывает веб инспектор: [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После применения display:none; все заработало. В Google Chrome 44 на Mac все в порядке, видимо проблема только с Safari

Comment: В сафари проблема с вычислением чисел с плавающей точкой, постоянно дробный остаток до 11 знака. Быстрый хак — подправьте условия завершения анимации в файле preload.js на if (el.style.opacity < 0.05)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло